# Insert return in formula field crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports, line-breaks, carriage-return

I have one field in SAP Crystal Report and I want to insert a carriage return in the middle of the value based on the appearance of a certain word.

Example:

Ring mat:1.4404 DrawNo:645321 Rev.A

Should look like:

Ring mat:14404
DrawNo:645321 Rev.A

In this, the return should always come before the word DrawNo:

Can someone give me a explanation how to do this?

I have tried different methods, but they're all based on a fix number of character. And the return is set after this number of characters.
Because the characters in front of DrawNo: are dynamic, i can't get it to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like:
Replace(YourValue, "DrawNo", Chr(10) + "DrawNo")

Turn on the property 'Can Grow'

Comment: Tried it, but does not work. Also used Chr(13) and ChrW, but no result

Comment: I mean that there is no reaction to this statement.  It seems not to do anything..

Comment: Check using instr() function that the string you are trying to replace indeed exists within the column.